# Extending maps on a Riemann surface

Tags: complex-analysis, riemann-surfaces

I came across the following definition for functions on a Riemann surface:

A nonconstant analytic function on a Riemann surface, $f_{1}:X_{1} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ extends $f_{0}:X_{0} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ if there is an embedding $j:X_{0} \rightarrow X_{1}$ such that $f_{0}=f_{1} \circ j$.

I am curious: if we have two extensions of $(X_{0},f_{0})$, then is there a third pair $(X_{3},f_{3})$ that extends both? This seems reasonable to me, but how might we prove this? Also, what is the use of this notion of extending a function on a Riemann surface?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider a torus $T$ and a cover $\{X_1, X_2, X_3\}$ of $T$ such that each $X_i$ is homeomorphic to $S^1\times (0,1)$. You can choose the $X_i$ as tubes, such that also $X_i\cap X_j$ as well as  $X_i\cup X_j$ is also homeomorphic to $S^1\times (0,1)$. Now if you analytically extend from $X_1$ to $ X_1\cup X_2$ and simultaneously to  $ X_1\cup X_3 $ you need to check whether the extension agree on $X_3$, which they will, in general, not.

This kind of extension is useful to explore the topology of Riemann surfaces, cause it allows you to construct (universal) coverings in a canonical way.

Comment: So generally such an $(X_{3}, f_{3})$ does not exist?

Comment: This is a tricky question ;-) To each Riemann surface there is a simply connected cover to which you may be able to lift the map, and there you may be able to extend it globally (unless you run into singularities). Unless you are looking at simply connected domains you will run into problems though. It is a bit like the question of extending functions defined on a subset of $S^1 $ to all of $S^1$, just two dimensional. A large part of the theory of Riemann surfaces is about this topic actually, it cannot be covered in such a short discussion.